# Using Registry module crashes Perl with Access Violation

Tags: windows, perl, registry, access-violation

Our perl program crashes when started on customer's Windows machine. Further tests shows that with the perl distribution we provide, a simple "hello world" script works, but breaks if it includes the line:

```
use Win32::TieRegistry(Delimiter=>'\\');
```

It crashes with Access Violation for accessing a zero pointer.
The stack points to **registry.dll**.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this problem? I didn't find anything about it in a google search, and can't recreate it in my environment.

Comment: Does the user in question have access to the registry?  If you are shipping your script into a company with locked down machines, the user might not have enough access to read or write to the registry.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I'll check that with the customer. Can this explain an access violation when "using" the TieRegistry module?

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me what version of perl you are using? Is it Activestate or Strawberry Perl?

An access violation is usually a programming error in some non perl code.  It looks like could be registry.dll that contains the error.  In order to track it down you would probably need source code and/or debugger. I am assuming that the registry.dll is a dll that comes as part of perl (ie XS/C code part of Win32::TieRegistry or Win32API::Registry that is used by Win32::TieRegistry).  To validate this assumption can you provide the full path to registry.dll?  I think it will show it in the Access Violation dialog box.

Comment: This was probably because on old mismatching Perl version was installed on the machine. A colleague found a workaround to the problem, but I don't know exactly what it is. Thanks anyway.